# IOS4.2 app quits with EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: objective-c, nsoperationqueue, ios-4.2

An iPad app that runs fine under IOS3 fails under IOS4.2 It has a class that runs an http session from an operation queue and the failure is linked to this activity. Here is the console output:

```
Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.
[Switching to thread 11523]
```

Running NSZombies enabled didn't reveal anything so I have been putting NSLog statements in the code and found that the crash occurs when a local variable is changed. Here is the code section:

```
self.currentOperation = [[[DeduceAccessOperation alloc] init] autorelease];
[self.currentOperation addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"isFinished"
 options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew | NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld)
 context:NULL];
NSLog (@"Start observer added");    
[operationQueue addOperation:self.currentOperation];
NSLog (@"Start operation added");
NSLog(@"State is %d", self.status);
self.status = IEnablerServiceUpdating;
NSLog (@"State updated");
```

And here is the console log output:

```
2010-12-08 21:26:44.548 UCiEnabler[5180:307] Start observer added
2010-12-08 21:26:44.550 UCiEnabler[5180:307] Start operation added
2010-12-08 21:26:44.552 UCiEnabler[5180:307] State is 1
Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.
[Switching to thread 11523]
```

It is like status has become read-only (It's property is declared as atomic and readwrite).

The other relevant piece of information is that a sub-view has just been changed and it triggers the call on the above routine. It's code is:

```
//Start the update      
UCiEnablerAppDelegate *controller = (UCiEnablerAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[controller deduceIEnablerServiceAccess];
controller.serviceBusy = TRUE; //1.04
```

Has anyone seen anything like this?

Has anyone ideas where to look next?

Regards
Robin

Here's the stack trace:

```
#0  0x34a80464 in objc_msgSend
#1  0x3119543e in NSKVOPendingNotificationCreate
#2  0x3119535a in NSKeyValuePushPendingNotificationPerThread
#3  0x3117009a in NSKeyValueWillChange
#4  0x311682c6 in -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObserverNotification) willChangeValueForKey:]
#5  0x311cc718 in _NSSetIntValueAndNotify
#6  0x000097ce in -[IEnablerService startDeducingAccessState] at IEnablerService.m:55
#7  0x00002bc0 in -[UCiEnablerAppDelegate deduceIEnablerServiceAccess] at UCiEnablerAppDelegate.m:100
#8  0x0000a33e in -[RootViewControlleriPad animationDidStop:finished:context:] at RootViewController-iPad.m:43
#9  0x341bb336 in -[UIViewAnimationState sendDelegateAnimationDidStop:finished:]
```

Comment: In future **please** review your question to make sure the code formatting is correct.

Comment: Also, run this in the debugger, obtain the stack trace and post it here.

Comment: no chance you have a custom setter for status that is causing the crash? What happens if you set a breakpoint on that line and step into the self.status = IEnablerServiceUpdating?

Comment: @Rog: could be.  I was thinking that some KVO was tripping over, which is why I want to see the stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

`NSOperationQueue` in iOS 4.2 now uses GrandCentralDispatch when starting `NSOperations`. [There's a Technical Q&A here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa2010/qa1712.html)

Pretty much the queue now calls the `NSOperation` subclass's `start` method in a new thread regardless of the `isConcurrent` property.  In my experience it means that if you are using `NSURLConnection` inside a `start` method your code will no longer run because the thread `start` is running on doesn't have an `NSRunLoop`.

Apple says that this change doesn't break compatibility because you were supposed to spawn a new thread in the `start` method anyway.

For backwards compatibility you should change your subclass from using `start` to using `run`.

Comment: My research into GCD suggests it is appropriate for dispatch queues (Concurrency Guide p13) not operation queues. But NSURLConnections should run from operation queues. But since iOS3 the better way for these to be called is through the asynchronous API calls. But I am unwilling/unable to revise the code as I don't have access to the environment to fully test it. Arrgghhhh!